# How to take backup of all the data of all the apps

Tags: windows-7, backup, android

I have some apps that contain information like Account summary, TO-DO list, Notes, Password saver etc. Recently I lost my cellphone so I lost all my app data as well. I don't want to lose my app data.  Is there any way I can backup all my app data to my PC and restore it back to my phone when required?.

So I want to take backup of all my android phone apps along with its data to my PC.

Comment: What's your phone model?

Comment: Its MICROMAX canvas 4 (a210).

Comment: Your question appears to be answered here: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296)

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of that phone model but if it has play store, you can configure play store to backup all your apps and their data to the cloud. Then you just set-up your samsung account on your replacement phone and all your apps and their data will be downloaded on that phone

Note:you will need a samsung account and it will only work if your replacement phone also has android operating system and play store.